# After Update of R and dplyr running time for dplyr::group_by function increases

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, runtime

I was recently running a R script developed under R 3.2.2 version with dplyr 0.5.0 under R 3.5.1 using dplyr 0.7.6. To my surprise the code took approximately 100 times longer to run than usual, which I traced to the use of the group_by function in the following expression where I:

```
matches=as.data.frame(df %>%
                       group_by(id) %>%
                       filter(living_quarters >= matching_living_quarters,
                              abs(age-matching_age) <= 4,
                              index<matching_index-lag_time,
                              sex==matching_sex) %>%
                       mutate(matched_id=matching_id))
```

I couldn't find any reason so far why the run time would be so much worse. Did group_by lead to parallel processing in earlier versions or does anybody have an insight why this staight forward use would be processed much slower by the updated version?

Comment: how fast is it if you move the `group_by()` to after the `filter()` and `mutate()` ?

Comment: good question, I tired it and for df with 136000 entries the running time went from almost a minute to a fraction of a second, which is what it used to be before the update of the version. In this case the grouping isn't necessary since each id only has one entry, so maybe the older version ignored the group_by command? However all my old algorithms have the same problem even when they only use group_by where it is absolutely necessary. Does it sound right to you that the code segment above takes one minute for a single execution for nrow(df)=136,000? The results don't change between versions.